# What are the differences between Dictionary Merge (|) & Update Operators (|=) Operators?

Tags: python, dictionary, merge

Python 3.9 adds in the Dictionary Merge (|) & Update Operators (|=) [announcement](https://docs.python.org/3.9/whatsnew/3.9.html#dictionary-merge-update-operators)

What are the differences between the two?
What -- if any -- differences are there between the update operator and dict.update?

Comment: A dupe of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64210846/when-to-use-dictionary-merge-vs-update-operator) post, but that's not a great target. I swear there was a good post covering this.

Comment: Did you read [the PEP](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0584/)? If not, do you still have any questions after reading the PEP?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I merge two dictionaries in a single expression in Python (taking union of dictionaries)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38987/how-do-i-merge-two-dictionaries-in-a-single-expression-in-python-taking-union-o)

Comment: @wim I did, of course. Is there some part of PEP 584 you think answers the question? I certainly don't see it.

Comment: Yes, the [specification](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0584/#specification) section of the PEP explains exactly what the new operators do and what the differences are, complete with examples. The [motivation](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0584/#dict-update) section explained the difference with `dict.update`. I don't think your question really shows the level of research effort we expect on stack overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are like other augmented operations. `|` creates a new dictionary like `{**d1, **d2}` does. `|=` updates an existing dictionary like `.update`.

```
>>> d1 = {1:1, 3:3}
>>> d2 = {2:2, 3:4}
>>> 
>>> d3 = d1 | d2
>>> d3
{1: 1, 3: 4, 2: 2}
>>> 
>>> d1 |= d2
>>> d1
{1: 1, 3: 4, 2: 2}
```